# Heroku: Connection to log stream failed. Please try again later. When trying to access the logs

Tags: heroku

I am running a Nodejs server on Heroku, but when I try to view/access the log I get this error message saying:

> Connection to log stream failed. Please try again later.

along with a popup that shows up at top right corner [image]

I went to check the logs for another Heroku project that I have and the same thing was happening there as well. Any ideas as for why that's happening?

Answer (score 2):

This issue occurs frequently even when the logs are not down as @JRichardsz suggested.

According to [Heroku's official documentation](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/logging)

> A real-time tail session is automatically terminated after one hour of inactivity.

This can cause your Log Stream to time out.

I also assume they have other flags in place that limit users when using logs.

It is common to face temporary blocks from logs when using them extensively, usually after waiting a few minutes you can run `heroku logs --tail` again and continue viewing the logs.

Answer (score -1):

Please don't go into a panic.

This message is due temporary incident in heroku platform at global level.

When this happens, also the **run console** shows a similar error.

In order to verify current status of heroku platform you could go to this site :

https://status.heroku.com/

Click on **INCIDENT** option and you will see the official message :

> Log Views Unavailable : Engineers are continuing to investigate the issue.

[image]

Although this rarely occurs :D

Comment: This is happening now and `heroku status` returns `No known issues at this time.` (for all 3 of Apps, Data and Tools)

Comment: I think this page status is for huge and/or apocalyptic errors.

Comment: I am back here again in 2020, same symptom, same (i.e. no) explanation. `heroku status` should be more reliable

Comment: Yes but  is the only thing that we have. Also this problem is temporary